# rosmake error" RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp"

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

whenever i am running rosmake i am getting the following output

File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 314, in build_or_recurse
self.build_or_recurse(d)
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 314, in build_or_recurse
self.build_or_recurse(d)
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 314, in build_or_recurse
self.build_or_recurse(d)
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 314, in build_or_recurse
self.build_or_recurse(d)
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 314, in build_or_recurse
self.build_or_recurse(d)
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 314, in build_or_recurse
self.build_or_recurse(d)
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 314, in build_or_recurse
self.build_or_recurse(d)
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 311, in build_or_recurse
if p in self.build_list:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163096/rosmake-error%22-runtimeerror:-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-in-cmp%22/) by [azazel](https://answers.ros.org/users/17811/azazel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is because you have a circular dependency in your dependencies (i.e. two packages that both depend on each other).

I am getting this error right now as well and am Googling for a good way to solve, so no advice yet :-) . This is my best guess for the cause because after making a circular dependency, this happened.

---

Originally posted by [mbforbes](https://answers.ros.org/users/15401/mbforbes/) with karma: 70 on 2014-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0